# Does anyone know if there is an English translation of this book?

Tags: books

It is a book written by Boris Zlotnik. I found some books from him in search, but I'm not sure whether the same book. Some titles with chess course vol.1, vol2., etc..

[image: It is a book written by Boris Zlotnik]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to prove that something does not exist, but I read and speak Russian, and I just looked at that book in Russian. It deals a lot with tabias of various openings, and resulting middlegames.

The only book of his in English I could find is "Chess : Knowledge, Training, Mastery", and that is definitely a different book, as I also have that in Russian: "Шахматы - Наука, Опыт, Мастерство (1990)" (strictly translated as "Chess: Science, Experience, Mastery").

Lastly, I found a site that seemed to say that it was only available in Russian, which I tend to agree with after researching it. Interestingly, he has a two-volume series in Spanish though, and one more in Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

Hold on, the translation is coming out in December!

[https://www.amazon.com/Zlotniks-Middlegame-Manual-Structures-Manoeuvres/dp/9056919261/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&qid=1595944036&refinements=p_27%3ABoris+Zlotnik&s=books&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9056919261)